# Rust Snafu Crate: no method named `fail` found for enum `Error` in the current scope

Tags: error-handling, rust

I'm trying to use the [Snafu](https://docs.rs/snafu/0.6.10/snafu/index.html) crate for some basic error handling. In this case, I'm trying to return an `Error` when `check_value()` is given anything but a `CustomInputValue::CiFloat`. Based on what I was seeing in examples on [this](https://docs.rs/snafu/0.6.10/snafu/guide/comparison/failure/index.html) page from the docs, I thought this would work:

```rust
use snafu::{Backtrace, ResultExt, Snafu, ensure};

#[derive(Debug, Snafu)]
pub enum Error{
    #[snafu(display("Incorrect Type: {:?}"), kind)]
    IncorrectInputType{kind: CustomInputValue},
}

#[derive(Debug, Clone, PartialEq)]
pub enum CustomInputValue{
    CiBool(bool),
    CiInt(i32),
    CiFloat(f64),
}

type Result<T, E = Error> = std::result::Result<T, E>;

fn main(){
    check_value(CustomInputValue::CiFloat(10.0));
}

fn check_value(val: CustomInputValue )->Result<()>{
    match val {
         CustomInputValue::CiFloat(inp)=>inp,
         _=>Error::IncorrectInputType{kind: val}.fail()?
    };
    Ok(())
}
```

However, this produces the error:

```
error[E0599]: no method named `fail` found for enum `Error` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:24:57
   |
4  | pub enum Error{
   | -------------- method `fail` not found for this
...
24 |                 _=>Error::IncorrectInputType{kind: val}.fail()?
   |                                                         ^^^^ method not found in `Error`
```

What's causing this error? Do I need to implement a fail function? I don't see anywhere in the docs such a custom `fail()` function being written for `Error`, and can't find anything bout requiring a `fail()` function for `Error` in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `#[derive(Snafu)]` attribute creates "context selectors" for each enum variant. That means that `Error::IncorrectInputType` refers to the variant, while `IncorrectInputType` is a generated struct which has the `fail()` method.

The fix is to use this selector instead of the enum:

```
match val {
     CustomInputValue::CiFloat(inp) => inp,
     _ => IncorrectInputType { kind: val }.fail()?
       // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no Error::
};
```

You can browse the rest of the [SNAFU user's guide](https://docs.rs/snafu/0.6.10/snafu/guide/index.html) to know more about the macro.

---

Also, the `kind` in the `#[snafu(display(...))]` attribute is misplaced. It should be a parameter within the display portion:

```
#[snafu(display("Incorrect Type: {:?}", kind))]
IncorrectInputType { kind: CustomInputValue },
```

Comment: How to I import this ```IncorrectInputType``` struct then? Currently getting an error: ```IncorrectInputType not found in this scope```

Comment: `IncorrectInputType` should already be visible in the scope where `Error` is. Did you apply both the fixes?

Comment: importing with ```use crate::{IncorrectInputType}``` solved the problem

Comment: Note that, as of version 0.7, SNAFU adds `Snafu` to the end of the generated context selectors to help avoid this confusion.